# Can't Enter Break Mode at this time Error

Tags: excel, vba, metaprogramming, breakpoints, vbe

I am trying to do the following in one module:

1. Replace a `Public Const` in another module, at run-time.
2. Invoke a procedure that uses the updated public constant

However, it throws an error:

> *Can't enter break mode at this time*

Although, it *does* update the public constant.

I tried pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> to resume execution, but it did not help. Any suggestions?

```
Sub AB()

    Call LoadQuoteDetails2.Automation

    Application.VBE _
               .ActiveVBProject _
               .VBComponents _
               .Item("mod00Admin") _
               .CodeModule _
               .ReplaceLine 2, "Public Const QuoteDB = ""A:\1.0 Projects\P0445 Ireland Commercial Raters\02 Analysis\05 Rate Assessor\ROI Fleet Rater\Quote Database\Quote DB June 18.accdb"""

    Call CalcTariffPrem

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you 'update' a public **constant**?

Comment: Using this, I am changing the declared public constant

Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Item("mod00Admin").CodeModule.ReplaceLine 2, "Public Const QuoteDB = ""A:\1.0 Projects\P0445 Ireland Commercial Raters\02 Analysis\05 Rate Assessor\ROI Fleet Rater\Quote Database\Quote DB June 18.accdb"""

Comment: You're trying to use the program modify a line that cannot be modified while the program is running:  If you tried doing this manually while stepping through with F8 then it would tell you that it required resetting the project.  The only way I can see to do this would be from a different application - you *might* be able to do it from a macro in a different DB, but I am doubtful

Comment: Overall, I would suggest that if this is expected to be a regular thing then you should instead store the data in a "Settings" table and retrieve from there at runtime.

Comment: First of all, if you want to change the value of that *constant*, then, **it is not a constant**. Second, the error could be caused because you need to set an option in Excel. make sure you check in Excel Options->Trusted Sites->Settings of Trusted Sites-> Macros Setting-> Check Trust access to Visual Basic Edito

Comment: @Jeeped I've taken the liberty to edit the post to clarify.

Comment: Side note: no need to use `Call`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use global variable or property instead of a "constant".  The reason you're getting the "Can't Enter Break Mode at this time" message is because you are modifying the `VBProject` *that is currently running*. Basically what is happening is that you are changing the source code while the ***already compiled code*** is still executing. A `Const` is "hard coded" into the executing procedure, so changing it won't do anything until the project is recompiled. In fact, the VBA language specification has no runtime semantics for [Const Declarations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200326.aspx) (why would it?).  For example...

```
Public Const EXAMPLE = "Foo"

Public Sub Test()
    Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Item("Module1").CodeModule.ReplaceLine 1, _
        "Public Const EXAMPLE = ""Bar"""
    Debug.Print EXAMPLE   '<-- prints Foo
End Sub
```

If you attempt to step through this with the debugger, you'll get the same message because the code in the VBE no longer matches what is being executed in the context of the debugger. Consider the following code:

```
'Module1
Public Const EXAMPLE = "Bar"

Public Sub Test()
    With Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Item("Module1").CodeModule
        .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
    End With
    Debug.Print "Where am I?"  '<-- this will still execute.
End Sub
```

If you step through this using <kbd>F8</kbd>, what line is the debugger supposed to highlight after you delete all of the code?

So, the [X to your Y](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is to simply not attempt to run self modifying code. A string that needs to change is not a constant - it is a variable. My recommendation would be to make it a property, give it a default value, and set it at run-time as needed:

```
'mod00Admin
Private Const DEFAULT_DB As String = "C:\Foo\Bar.accdb"
Private activeQuoteDB As String

Public Property Let QuoteDB(rhs As String)
    activeQuoteDB = rhs
End Property

Public Property Get QuoteDB() As String
    If activeQuoteDB = vbNullString Then
        QuoteDB = DEFAULT_DB
    Else
        QuoteDB = activeQuoteDB
    End If
End Property

'...

Public Sub AB()
    LoadQuoteDetails2.Automation
    mod00Admin.QuoteDB = "A:\1.0 Projects\P0445 Ireland Commercial Raters\02 Analysis\05 Rate Assessor\ROI Fleet Rater\Quote Database\Quote DB June 18.accdb"
    CalcTariffPrem
End Sub
```