# "Can't enter break mode at this time" with OLE Objects

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I am trying to delete all active x control buttons in a worksheet with the following code:

```
ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Delete
```

When buttons actually exist, I get a "Can't enter break mode at this time" error when stepping through the code. Furthermore, when I try to call it within a module with other code, Excel crashes completely (especially if I'm trying to delete a sheet that had the control buttons). Is there a known issue when working with OLE Objects/Active X controls?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404306/cant-enter-break-mode-at-this-time-error

Comment: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/cant-enter-break-mode-at-this-time.380662/